# Измерение покрытия тестами с помощью Jacoco падает в проекте на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing

Добавил в проект плагин `jacoco-android` для измерения покрытия тестами с помощью Jacoco. Проект на Kotlin. Получаю на этапе `jacocoTestDebugUnitTestReport` ошибки вроде вот такой:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: …./video/showlist/list/view/VideoListAdapter$MyViewHolder$show$inlined$let$lambda$1.class (No such file or directory)
```

Файл такой на самом деле есть, но в имени файла на один `$` больше: `VideoListAdapter$MyViewHolder$show$$inlined$let$lambda$1.class`

Сначала я на эти грабли наступил с автогенеренными классами Moxy. После того, как их исключил, начали осыпаться котлиновские лямбды. Если и их исключить, то все работает, но это уже неправильно: в них значимая часть кода.

Вот [коммит](https://github.com/tseglevskiy/medialib_android/commit/5b6777c9f09a5c27b0e46dc467fe572255eee7f2), в котором видно, как я эту штуку включал (в нем плохой воркэраунд - `'**/*inlined*.class'` исключены). Я [тикет](https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin/issues/28) в плагине открыл, но у меня нет уверенности, что это действительно бага.

Есть идеи, как чинить?